# vimdiff / vim -d -- how to show only the differences and fold all identical lines?

Tags: vim, vimdiff

Is there a way we can exclude the lines which are same in the below output? I did a vim -d file1 file2 but its showing the differences and also some additions lines before and after the differences. How to exclude that?

In the attached example 131, 132, 134, 136 etc are same in both the files but its still getting displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 23):

You can do this once off by setting options on the `vimdiff` command:

```
vimdiff -c 'set diffopt=filler,context:0' file1 file2
```

Alternatively, add to your `.vimrc`:

```
set diffopt=filler,context:0
```

Or, once in `vimdiff`, set this temporarily with

```
:set diffopt=filler,context:0
```

This will tell `vimdiff` (or if you prefer, `vim -d`) to *not* provide the full context for the lines in which differences were found.  Consecutive  lines with no changes will be "folded".